# How do I change the color scheme in microsoft office 2010

Tags: microsoft-office

I have a friend that changed the color scheme of his office installation on his laptop and I want to change mine so its black like his also, how do I do this?

If I have to change the Microsoft Office files, I won't be able to do that as this is on my school laptop and I can't access anything on the hdd.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To change the colour scheme, click `File` and then `Options` towards the bottom.
[image: File Menu]

After clicking options, this dialogue will show up and you can then use the `Colour Scheme` drop down to change the colour of your office installation.

[image: Options]

**Note:** This setting is global and set for all Microsoft Office applications. I don't know of a way to change it for one application.

Images from [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/18326/change-the-default-color-scheme-in-office-2010/).